# How can I download the backups ClockworkMod creates to my PC?

Tags: backup

I do not see them in the /clockworkmod folder when I connect my device to my PC.  I tried using adb pull but adb does not show any devices when the device is in recovery mode (only if it's booted).

Version is 4.2.1; ROM Cyanogen.  Device is MAKO, and my PC is running Windows 7. The drivers for the device have already been added/installed from the android-sdk extras folder.  The folders I see when I connect the device to win7 are different than those I see when I browse on the device itself.

This issue might pertain to [the way 4.2.1/4.2.2 creates folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005176/adb-not-recognising-nexus-4) (something about multi-user).

Comment: Have you tried using file manager app, and verify if the folder really exist in the phone? It's silly, but better make sure.

Comment: Can you grab screenshots to help, particularly *The folders I see when I connect the device to win7 are different than those I see when I browse on the device itself*

Comment: ADB does not work when you are in recovery. Only fastboot does.

Comment: `adb does not show any devices when the device is in recovery mode` -- so why are you in recovery mode?  CWM backups aren't deleted when the device boots.

Answer (score 3):

The ROM Manager app has an option in the Manage and Restore Backups to Download Backups. You might want to try using it to create backups and download those backups to your computer.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Choose Download Backups and you will see:

[image: IMG:]

Provided your phone and your computer are logged into the same network you can point your browser to the address shown on the screen and choose which of the backups you would like to transfer to your computer.

It will take a while depending on the size of the backup.

This may be a feature of the Pro Version but the Pro version is worth every penny.

Good Luck.

Comment: thanks for that! I've found that using recovery to handle backups to be easier, but this seems to change that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use adb for copy backups:

```
adb pull /mnt/shell/emulated/clockworkmod/
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if the following will solve your Problems, but I had similar problems with my Nexus 4 (mako)

First up: The Backups will probably be stored in "/data/media/clockworkmod" you  probably won't find them somewhere else.

Second Problem: I had the same Problem, with not getting ADB-Access in Recovery Mode what I did was (Windows) going to Device Manager and selected "ADB Composite Interface" for the unknown device. Automatic driver searching did not succeed.